# send password link on self registeration

Tags: email, partner-communities

I have made a controller of self user registration . and while doing this what i am trying to make is that when ever user registered  a password link should be sent on user email id ,just like when ever we create a  org and sales force send a email verification link on our email id. Is it possible to do so?

```
public with sharing class CommunitiesSelfRegController {

    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }
    public String fPhone { get; set; }

    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {}

    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    public PageReference registerUser() {

        // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    

         String profileId = '00e90000001jxLE'; // To be filled in by customer.
         String roleEnum = 'Partner User'; // To be filled in by customer.
         String accountId = ''; // To be filled in by customer.
         String CityOffice='00590000003BnUR';
         String StateOffice='00590000003BnSa';
         String Owner='00590000003Bn3L';   // sytem Admin ID 
         String AccountNumber;
         Account account= new Account();
         account.Name =firstName;
         account.SPBE__First_Name__c= firstName;
         account.SPBE__Last_Name__c = lastName;        
         account.SPBE__Email__c=email;
         insert account;         

         account.OwnerId=Owner;
        // account.isPartner=true;

         update account;
         AccountNumber=account.Account_Number__c;
        accountId = account.Id;
        String userName = email;
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = userName;
        u.Email = email;
        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.LastName = lastName;
        u.CommunityNickname = firstName+AccountNumber;
        u.CompanyName=CompanyName;
        u.Phone=fPhone;
        u.SPBE__City_Office__c=CityOffice;
        u.SPBE__State_Office__c=StateOffice;
        u.ProfileId = profileId;

        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password); 

        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(userName, password, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startURL'));
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured any email template for this mail? Make sure email template needs to include this special merge field

> {!Community_Url}

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What this expression will do?